# The result of the script to get the area value is wrong

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I wrote a script to find the area of the room, But The result is incorrect.

In order to obtain the area of the room, except ceiling '
(W of wall① * room height)*2 + (W of wall② * room height)*2 = total wall area value
I wrote it as above.
The floor area is when the checkbox is checked
(W of wall① *W of wall②) + Total wall area value = Room area value excluding ceiling
I wrote it so that it comes out as above, but the result value keeps coming out wrong.

For example, if the W of the wall① is 4, the W of the wall② is 2, and the height is 3, the answer is 36 for the area excluding the floor area and the ceiling area.
But it is extracted as 28.
Naturally, even if you include the floor area value, the value is different.

I'm still studying scripts and I don't really know what's wrong because I don't know very well.
Help..!

※I used a translator because I couldn't speak English. That is why my words may not be natural. Please understand.

```js
function btnResult() {
    var MyWidth = eval(document.getElementById("Value01").value);
    var MyLength = eval(document.getElementById("Value02").value);
    var MyHeight = eval(document.getElementById("Value03").value);
 
    if (!MyWidth) {
        alert("Pelase, Check.");
        document.getElementById("Value01").focus();
        return false;
    } else if (!MyHeight) {
        alert("Pelase, Check.");
        document.getElementById("Value02").focus();
        return false;
    } else if (!MyLength) {
        alert("Pelase, Check.");
        document.getElementById("Value03").focus();
        return false;
    } else {
 
        var data01 = (MyWidth * MyHeight) * 2;
        var data02 = (MyLength * MyHeight) * 2;
        var data03 = MyWidth * MyLength;
 
        var TotalResult = data01 + data02;
 
        var addGCheck = $('.add_Ground').is(':checked');
 
        if (addGCheck) {
            TotalResult = data01 + data02 + data03;
        }
        document.getElementById("resultA").innerHTML = Number(TotalResult.toFixed(1));
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="Box">
    <div class="Inner">
        <div class="List">
            <span class="Title">W</span>
            <input type="text" id="Value01" class="ValueBox">
            <span class="Unit">m</span>
        </div>
        <div class="List">
            <span class="Title">L</span>
            <input type="text" id="Value03" class="ValueBox">
            <span class="Unit">m</span>
        </div>
        <div class="List">
            <span class="Title">H</span>
            <input type="text" id="Value02" class="ValueBox">
            <span class="Unit">m</span>
        </div>
         
        <span class="addCheck"><input type="checkbox" class="add_Ground" name="addGround">Add Ground</span>
          
        <div class="Btn">
            <input type="button" id="btnSum" class="btnSum" value="value" onclick="btnResult()">
        </div>
 
        <div class="ValueCont">
            <span class="ValueTitle">Total Value</span>
            <p id="resultA" class="resultValue"></p>
            <span class="ValueUnit">m<sup>2</sup></span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: DON'T use the `script` tag. Every SO question is about scripts one way or another. It's no better than adding `code` as a tag. That tag is just noise, it was deleted in the past and will be deleted very soon again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get the wrong input id, you inverted input L and input H in your selector.
I modify your snippest to make it done.
I recommend you to console.log() your data, when you want to track / debug your function.

```js
function btnResult() {

    var MyWidth = eval(document.getElementById("Value01").value);
    var MyLength = eval(document.getElementById("Value02").value);
    var MyHeight = eval(document.getElementById("Value03").value);
  console.log(MyWidth,MyLength,MyHeight);
    if (!MyWidth) {
        alert("Pelase, Check.");
        document.getElementById("Value01").focus();
        return false;
    } else if (!MyHeight) {
        alert("Pelase, Check.");
        document.getElementById("Value02").focus();
        return false;
    } else if (!MyLength) {
        alert("Pelase, Check.");
        document.getElementById("Value03").focus();
        return false;
    } else {
 
        var data01 = (MyWidth * MyHeight) * 2;
        var data02 = (MyLength * MyHeight) * 2;
        var data03 = MyWidth * MyLength;

        var TotalResult = data01 + data02;
 
        var addGCheck = $('.add_Ground').is(':checked');
 
        if (addGCheck) {
            TotalResult = data01 + data02 + data03;
        }
        document.getElementById("resultA").innerHTML = Number(TotalResult.toFixed(1));
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="Box">
    <div class="Inner">
        <div class="List">
            <span class="Title">W</span>
            <input type="text" id="Value01"  class="ValueBox">
            <span class="Unit">m</span>
        </div>
        <div class="List">
            <span class="Title">L</span>
            <input type="text" id="Value02"  class="ValueBox">
            <span class="Unit">m</span>
        </div>
        <div class="List">
            <span class="Title">H</span>
            <input type="text" id="Value03"  class="ValueBox">
            <span class="Unit">m</span>
        </div>
         
        <span class="addCheck"><input type="checkbox" class="add_Ground" name="addGround">Add Ground</span>
          
        <div class="Btn">
            <input type="button" id="btnSum" class="btnSum" value="value" onclick="btnResult()">
        </div>
 
        <div class="ValueCont">
            <span class="ValueTitle">Total Value</span>
            <p id="resultA" class="resultValue"></p>
            <span class="ValueUnit">m<sup>2</sup></span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for answering my question!
It became a great help, thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, but you need to convert variables type to number. Let's hope, this answer will help you.

like,

```
    var data01 = (Number(MyWidth) * Number(MyHeight)) * 2;
    var data02 = (Number(MyLength) * Number(MyHeight)) * 2;
    var data03 = Number(MyWidth) * Number(MyLength);

    var TotalResult = Number(data01) + Number(data02);

    var addGCheck = $('.add_Ground').is(':checked');

    if (addGCheck) {
        TotalResult = Number(data01) + Number(data02) + Number(data03);
    }
```

shorthand: (add `+` sign before each numeric variable),

```
var data01 = (+MyWidth * +MyHeight) * 2;
var data02 = (+MyLength * +MyHeight) * 2;
var data03 = +MyWidth * +MyLength;

var TotalResult = +data01 + +data02;

var addGCheck = $('.add_Ground').is(':checked');

if (addGCheck) {
    TotalResult = +data01 + +data02 + +data03;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answering my question!